# How to convert tinymce generated html to MS Word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, tinymce, rtf, docx

I need to convert tinymce generated html to MS Word document without changing it.

The html contains images in base64 format.

Can anyone suggest some good third party tool or some open source dll to achieve it in C#?

So far I have tried a few (html to rtf dll pro and aspose) but none of them were able to get the desired result.

Comment: those who are voting to close please write a comment so that I may know what is wrong in this question

Comment: +1 a good question, i don't know why one would want ot close it

Comment: @Thariama The accepted answer has link for php library. I need in C#

Answer (score 1):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert html to Docx **and is free** and probably a good choice because your editor doesn't allow for very complex formatting.

Pandoc reads the HTML with http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pandoc/1.11.1/doc/html/Text-Pandoc-Writers-Docx.html and saves the docx with http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pandoc/1.11.1/doc/html/Text-Pandoc-Writers-Docx.html

It supports:

- h1-h6
- Blockquotes
- Images (not sure it works with Data URIs)
- Tables and lists
- Simple formatting: `<b>` and `<em>`
- Links

Howewer, it doesn't support (I think):

- text-alignment

Comment: Thanks @edi, I m going to try this